# Navigation bar position

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

[image]

I connected navigation bar to my view. At view define method:

```
class SettingsViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationBarDelegate {

    func positionForBar(bar: UIBarPositioning) -> UIBarPosition {
        return UIBarPosition.TopAttached
    }

}
```

But position still wrong.

Comment: how did u connect it ? Did you embed it or did u just drag and drop the navigation bar ?

Comment: Yes i connected it. Look at screenshot: http://storage8.static.itmages.ru/i/15/1105/h_1446731859_9597493_6a0f034ef5.png

Comment: look at the view debugger, try to move the navigation bar down in the IB

Comment: no effect, it seems i forget something connect...

Comment: can u move the navigation bar using size inspector ?

Comment: At which point in the loading of the view are you retrieving this position? I'd recommend trying after the view has appeared to make sure this isn't the problem.